# malloc_default_zone difference between macOS Monterey and Ventura

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

I am running this code on Monterey, compiled with Apple clang 14.0.0, and there the custom function `my_malloc` is called.
When I run the same code on Ventura, compiled with Apple clang 14.0.3, then `my_malloc` is not called.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include <signal.h>

void *(*system_malloc)(malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size);

void *my_malloc(malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size) {
    kill(0, SIGABRT);
    return 0;
}

void setup_intercept() {
    malloc_zone_t *zone = malloc_default_zone();
    system_malloc = zone->malloc;
    zone->malloc = my_malloc;
}

void reverse_intercept() {
    malloc_zone_t *zone = malloc_default_zone();
    zone->malloc = system_malloc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setup_intercept();
    void* v = malloc(42);
    reverse_intercept();
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference here? [I can see that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) the upstream LLVM Clang version went from 14 to 15 between these Apple Clang versions.

Looking at Compiler Explorer, the assembly looks a bit different. [With Clang 14](https://godbolt.org/z/KKaxss3za), there is just a call to `malloc`. [With Clang 15](https://godbolt.org/z/8nbhTrzsd), there is a call to `malloc@PLT`. I am not sure though if this is related to the issue with `malloc_default_zone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the memory where functions pointers are stored is protected.

This works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>

malloc_zone_t* getTheDefault() {
    malloc_zone_t **zones = nullptr;
    unsigned int num_zones = 0;

    if (KERN_SUCCESS != malloc_get_all_zones(0, NULL,
                                             (vm_address_t**)&zones, &num_zones)) {
        // Reset the value in case the failure happened after it was
        num_zones = 0;
    }
    if (num_zones) {
        return zones[0];
    }
    return malloc_default_zone();
}

using malloc_ptr = void*(malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size);
malloc_ptr* original_malloc;

void *my_malloc(malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size) {
    return original_malloc(zone, size);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    auto defaultZone = getTheDefault();
    original_malloc = defaultZone->malloc;

    vm_protect(mach_task_self(), (uintptr_t)defaultZone, sizeof(malloc_zone_t), 0,
               VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE);

    defaultZone->malloc = my_malloc;
    void* v = malloc(123);
    return 0;
}
```